# the absolute value of a measurable set is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a set $A$ that is a measurable set, does it follow that

$$E = \{ |x| : x \in A \} $$

is also measurable??

Comment: Is $A\subset\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: yes it lives in the reals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A\subset\mathbf{R}$, your set $E$ is just $(A\cup-A)\cap[0,\infty)$, so it is measurable.

For $A\subset\mathbf{R}^2$ (and $|\cdot|$ Euclidean norm) the assertion need not hold. Just take a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and think of it as a subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$. Then $\mu(A)=0$ but $E$ is non-measurable.

Comment: For the first part, Im having hard time seeing why $E$ is just the set you mentioned. Can you explain a bit more why it is so? thjanks

Comment: This sort of thing just takes careful thought and practice. Suppose $x\in A$. If $x\geq 0$ then $|x|=x\in A$. If $x\leq0$ then $|x|=-x\in -A$. In either case $|x|\in A\cup-A$. Since $|x|\geq0$, $|x|\in(A\cup-A)\cap[0,\infty)$. Similarly, if $y\in(A\cup-A)\cap[0,\infty)$ then there exists $x\in A$ such that $|x|=y$.